# Nesting Backbone models or collections so that they are linked

Tags: api, backbone.js, collections, model, entity-relationship

I have a `User` entity that has a `subscriptions` property. This is an array of IDs.

When I perform a fetch, the API will populate those `subscriptions`, and return something like this:

```
{
  subscriptions: [1, 2, 3],
  __subscriptions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Example'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Example'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Example'
    }
  ]
}
```

I have done this so that I can still perform actions on the original `subscriptions` and then save them back to the API. Any changes I make to `__subscriptions` will not be persisted as the API doesn't recognise this field – it is simply the populated data.

In the `parse` function of my `User`, I create the nested collection:

```
parse: function (response) {
  this.subscriptions = new Subscriptions(response.__subscriptions)
}
```

However, if I want to remove a subscription, I have to splice it from the `subscriptions` field of the `User` entity, and then I also have to remove it from the `subscriptions` collected that is nested as a property on the `User`:

```
// Clone the subscriptions property, delete the model with a matching ID, and then set it again.
var value = _.clone(this.get('subscriptions'))

// Use splice instead of delete so that we don't leave an undefined value
// in the array
value.splice(value.indexOf(model.id), 1)

// Also remove the same model from the nested collection
var removedSubscription = this.subscriptions.get(model)
this.subscriptions.remove(removedSubscription)

this.set('subscriptions', value)
this.save()
```

This is sort of annoying. Ideally, removing an ID from the `subscriptions` property should automatically update the collection.

Does this seem like a good way to deal with nested models and collections? I've heard bad things about Backbone.Relational so I was interested in a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would listen to events of Subscriptions collection and update subscriptions argument accordingly.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function () {
    this.subscriptions = new Subscriptions;
    this.subscriptions.on('add remove', this.updateSubscriptions, this)
  },

  updateSubscriptions: function() {
    this.set('subscriptions', this.subscriptions.pluck('id'))
  },

  parse: function (response) {
    this.subscriptions.reset(response.__subscriptions);
    return Backbone.Model.parse.call(this, response);
  }

});
```

So then removing subscription will update `subscriptions` attribute of user model:

```
user.subscriptions.remove(subscription)
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution for linking them. How do you handle relations and nesting, though? I'm not too sure about the way I'm doing things.